# Fastest Way To Round Number Inside List of Strings Python

Tags: python, regex, string

Given a list (can be numpy array) of addresses:

```
>input: ['F/O 1751 HOBART PL NW', '11TH ST NW 2301', '801 MT VERNON ST NW']
```

where the number doesn't always occur at the same place in the string. Is there a faster way than first extracting the number with regex and then inserting it back somehow in order to round it to the nearest (lets say) 100.

```
>output: ['F/O 1800 HOBART PL NW', '11TH ST NW 2300', '800 MT VERNON ST NW']
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you,

EDIT:

Only Numbers delimited by word boundaries (space, period, comma) would need to be converted so r'\b\d+\b' would work.

Comment: Can we see your regex based code? By the way don't "insert it back somehow", use `re.sub` to replace it.

Comment: How do you know that the second one should be `11TH ST NW 2300` instead of, say, `00TH ST NW 2301`? What's the rule for that?

Comment: Following up on @AshwiniChaudhary: Note that `sub` can take a function, so all you need to do is pass it `lambda x: str(round(int(x), -2))`.

Comment: Anyway, you ask about "faster". Do you actually mean CPU time? I find it hard to believe this is actually a bottleneck in a real program, and I wouldn't want to write/read/maintain something that's 10 times as complex as a simple `re.sub` call if it didn't actually make any difference in your real code.

Comment: (Although I'd guess subbing `(\d+)(\d\d)` with `\g<1>00` would be faster than subbing it would a function, and not _that_ must harder to read.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a little [text munging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#text-munging) with `re.sub()`:

```
import re

def replace_number(n):
    return str(int(round(int(n.group(0)), -2)))

data = ['F/O 1751 HOBART PL NW', '11TH ST NW 2301', '801 MT VERNON ST NW']

## I'm assuming you only want to munge numbers with 3 or more digits:
for datum in data:
    print re.sub(r"(\d{3,})", replace_number, datum)
```

output:

```
F/O 1800 HOBART PL NW
11TH ST NW 2300
800 MT VERNON ST NW
```

**Note** - this will give you potentially undesirable results if there is a number like 020 in the string:

```
'020 MT VERNON ST NW'
```

becomes

```
'0 MT VERNON ST NW'
```

If you expect to find that in your data, you'll need to add some checks to the `replace_number(n)` function

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for numbers delimited by word boundaries. I updated my question and I will use r'\b\d+\b' with your answer

Answer (score 1):

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/HUJi0S)

Here is my solution. Fairly simple to understand - it loops through each item in the list, handles it on a string by string basis. It finds all numbers larger than 3 digits or more in that particular string, then replaces it with a rounded version. It finally prints everything.

```
import re
l = ['F/O 1751 HOBART PL NW', '11TH ST NW 2301', '801 MT VERNON ST NW']
for i in l:
    a = re.findall(r'(\d{3,})', i)
    s = re.sub( str(a[0]), str(round(int(a[0]),-2)), i)
    print(s)
```

This outputs the following:

```
F/O 1800 HOBART PL NW
11TH ST NW 2300
800 MT VERNON ST NW
```